# Understanding Processor responsibility in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am planning to build a processor that transforms data into a wrapped object of Update, Delete, Insert operations. The flow would be:

Reader -> Processor (Fetch data from Database -> Check if already exists or not -> transform and wrap the same into the CRUD Object which stores the object and the CRUD Operation to perform in db).

Is giving the above responsibility to the above object correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data transformation is a typical use case of an [ItemProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/processor.html#itemProcessor), that is why the signature of the `process` method uses two generic types for the input/output (which could the same type if no data transformation is done).

The item processor you described is correct. However, it should not really read the data (this is the responsibility of the item reader). You can perform a query in the item processor to get additional details about the current item, but reading the main data (that drives the step) should be done by the item reader.

Comment: Thank you so much Mahmoud Ben so actively taking up the queries!. 
Adding a bit more to above - So I am reading actual data to be processed in reader itself. Further to check if it is update/delete/insert (its current state in database), I will pull the data in the processor and comparing the reader data with it. Is that correct in design? Again Thanks for help!

Comment: Updating the steps:
Reader - Get new data
Processor - Transform the new data to business domain object and get existing data from database and compare if it is insert/del/update. Transform again to a Wrapped object
Writer - Redirect the wrapped object to required Update/Insert/Del queries.

Comment: Yes, that seems a cleanly designed workflow to me. Always glad to help!